# populate form fields with php

Tags: php, html

I have a form for users to fill out information and am wondering how to retain the previously typed information if the user redirects back to the page.

So, I have two files,

- form.html
- validate.php

Under `form.html`:

```
<form id="regForm" action="index.php?validate" method="post" onsubmit="return regValidation();" >

<tr>
  <td width="150px" >First Name: <font color="red">*</font> </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="firstNameField" id="firstNameField" value/ ></td>
</tr>
```

and under `validate.php`, I have stored the info with $_SESSION:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['first'] = $_POST['firstNameField'];
?>
```

but when I tried to populate the `firstNameField` with `$_SESSION['first']` as follow

```
<td><input type="text" name="firstNameField" id="firstNameField" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['first']) ? $_SESSION['first'] : NULL; ?>" /></td>
```

The field will literally be replaced with `<?php echo isset($_SESSION['first']) ? $_SESSION['first'] : NULL; ?>`

Can someone tell me why and how to properly fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: your form should not be in html file. should be in php file also. php code in html file won't work.try putting your form in php file and lets see if it works.

Comment: Unless you configure apache to send .html files through the php parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the file name to `form.php` instead of `form.html` so Apache knows to parse PHP inside that file.

Alternatively you can modify your `.htaccess` file and add a line like this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

This tells Apache to to render all files that end in HTML using PHP.

Comment: So, are you saying that you display a form with similar appearance from both the html file and the php file? If so, why not display it from a single place - populating it or not, based on whether data has already been entered?

Comment: What are you talking about? Rename `form.php` and then `<?php ?>` tags do not show up as they are processed.

Comment: Sorry mate, I should've made it explicitly clear this was a response to a comment by the OP - one that has since been deleted. (s)he said that the php was in Validate.php and the form was in form.html - looking at the provided source code, it seemed apparent that there were two files that caused essentially the same HTML to be emitted. I agree - without the original comment, mine makes less than no sense at all. You must've wondered wtf I was thinking. :grin:

Comment: Ahhhh no worries.  Just had me incredibly confused.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Why make this complicated by having two files?

Just have the one.

The first time around nowt is filled in as the $_POST has nothing in it. Subsequent times that variable will have the appropriate value.

This will save you a lot of heartache in the future as you do not need to keep two files in step.

Also it removes the complexity of using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

By default, any file with the file extension of .html will not be parsed, therefore exposing `<?php $yourCode->exposed = true; ?>`

If you rename the same file, changing its file extension from .html to .php, then 
`<?php echo 'HelloWorld'; ?>` will be parsed, and the end result is `HelloWorld`

This default behavior can be overridden as described above by Tim

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name to form.php instead of form.html as  is the php tag

or add .html handler